# Is the full path required to unstage a file in GIT if am currenlty under a sub-directory?

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-reset, git-status, git-revert

**Repo: mergetest**

**$pwd**

/gitvobs/mergetest/apple

**$git status**

On branch br1

Changed but not updated:

(use "git add ..." to update what will be committed)

(use "git checkout -- ..." to discard changes in working directory)

```
   **modified:   inside**
```

**$git checkout inside**

error: pathspec 'inside' did not match any file(s) known to git.

**$git checkout apple/inside** works perfect

So every-time, do i need to specify the full path of a file to unstage changes when am within a sub-directory?

This is not the case with add (i can add file using 'git add file-name' anywhere)

Is this the way GIT behaves or is this changed in other versions of GIT?

Am using git version 1.6.6

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On git version 1.7.1, I can use `git checkout inside` to revert the file. Here's [the commit](http://repo.or.cz/w/git.git/commit/efad1a5615e80637dcb38c8eaa1e35c03b24169f) which introduced the feature, if you're curious.

*Edit:* Actually, it works in git version 1.5.6.5 as well. So I'm not sure what this means.